# How to sort a HashMap by Keys and then Values?

Tags: java

I have the following HashMap

```
HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> calHash new HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event>();
```

I am able to sort it by keys by doing this:

```
SortedSet<GregorianCalendar> keys = new TreeSet<GregorianCalendar>(calHash.keySet());
```

I also made my Event class implement Comparable and overwrote the compareTo method as follows:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Object e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       int hour = ((Event) e).getStartTime().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       int minute = ((Event) e).getStartTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       int anotherHour = this.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       int anotherMinute = this.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

       if(anotherHour - hour == 0 ){
           return anotherMinute - minute;
       }else{
           return anotherHour - hour;
       }


    return 0;

    }
}
```

With the above, I can sort my Events (values) by ascending order. Now my question is, how can I sort my HashMap first by keys and then if the same key has multiple values (events scheduled with different times) sort it my values after that?

I can only seem to find how to sort one way or the other but now a double sort by both.

Comment: You probably better first check in your `compareTo` function that `e` is indeed an event. Otherwise you will throw a cast exception...

Comment: @CommuSoft It's not a problem. It's just my small program, so I know that it's an Event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `calHash.entrySet()`. This will give you a set of [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html), which you can then dump into a `new LinkedList<Map.Entry>(entrySet)`.

You can then sort that list using `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` with a custom comparator that sorts those entries by one criteria, and if that criteria is the same, then by the other criteria.

Here's an example anonymous comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry>() {
    public int compare(Map.Entry e1, Map.Entry e2) {
       // do comparisons here
       return 0;    
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this is probably going to be bad, I don't know how to format comments. But I did this:    Set<Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>> map = (MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().entrySet()); 
   
   LinkedList<Map.Entry> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry>(map);  But now I'm not sure how to do the comparator. Can I reuse the compareTo method that I already wrote?

Comment: Gotcha - yeah, you can do something very similar to it, but you should use an anonymous comparator. I've added a sample above.

Comment: How can I go from Map.Entry to an Event? For the Comparator body, I can't do return ( e1.getValue()).compareTo(e2.getValue()); and I can't do return compareTo(list); Sorry if this is very basic.

Comment: Do `Comparator<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>>`, and add `<GregorianCalendar, Event>` to the params of the compare method as well. Then you can use `getKey` / `getValue` without needing to cast. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

Comment: If I do that, they sort complains saying "The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Map.Entry>, new Comparator<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event>>(){})"

Comment: Maybe you want List<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>> on the left side there? If that doesn't work out, you might want to ask a new question, since it'd be easier to deal with there (after accepting the answer that best answers this current question - seeing that you accept answers in your previous questions encourages people to answer your future questions.)

Comment: Yeah, no good. But thank you for your help. I'll post it again, perhaps with my whole method.

Answer (score 1):

A Map can't have multiple entries with the same key so it takes a little more work to sort by keys AND then values.

Perhaps the easiest way would be to make a new `Map<GregorianCalendar, List<Event>>` where each entry in the Map maps one key to a list of events.

If you have multiple events with the same time, then you would add the event to the list.

You could then sort the list using `Collections.sort()`.

By the way, you can create a sorted Map using `TreeMap` instead of creating a Hashmap and then making a separate SortedSet of just the keys.

```
Map<GregorianCalendar, List<Event>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```